# Raspberry Pi emulate phone Bluetooth stack

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth

I'd like to use my Raspberry Pi to emulate phone Bluetooth stack. I'd like to get it paired with car radio, simulate arriving/outgoing call, simulate SMS and the more alerts/notifications I can manage.

Below are some solutions I deepen, useful but not exactly what I need (thanks also to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076898/emulate-a-bluetooth-device-from-pc and https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/can-i-emulate-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-my-android-device):

- **oFono** (https://01.org/ofono)

  *allow controlling a real phone by another device. As other similar hands-free phones projects, it is not what I need: I would like to emulate Bluetooth stack, not controlling a real phone from another device. Devices involved should be car radio interface and Raspberry Pi: no real phone should be involved.*
- **BT-Sim** (http://btsim.sourceforge.net/index.html)

  *is about simulating hardware interface. Not needed for the moment.*

May someone suggests which is the best library or framework to work on, to accomplish this aim? Someone already played with a similar project? Any useful info?

Thank you

Comment: found this ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles ......... you will need to investigate three profiles ..... `Headset Profile (HSP)`, `Message Access Profile (MAP)` and `Phone Book Access Profile (PBAP, PBA)`

Comment: https://github.com/lukasjapan/bt-speaker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default linux bluetooth stack ([bluez](http://www.bluez.org/)) will let you create any type of bluetooth device you want.

Answer (score 2):

I find helpful this project too: https://github.com/nccgroup/nOBEX

> nOBEX allows emulating the PBAP, MAP, and HFP profiles to test vehicle infotainment systems and similar devices using these profiles. nOBEX provides PBAP and MAP clients to clone the genuine virtual filesystems for these profiles from a real phones. This means downloading the entire phone book and all text messages. Raw vcards, XML listings, and MAP BMSG structures are stored, and can be modified as desired for negative testing. nOBEX can then act as a PBAP and MAP server, allowing vehicles and other devices to connect to it and retrieve phone book and message information. Vcards, BMSGs, and XML listings are sent exactly as saved, allowing malformed user modified data to go through. Since most vehicle head units require HFP support before they attempt using PBAP and MAP, nOBEX also provides rudimentary support for HFP. It will send back user customizable preset responses to AT commands coming from the vehicle's head unit. This allows mimicking a real cell phone.